# Распознавание цифр из изображение

Tags: python, изображения, tesseract

Нужно распознать текст и вывести сперва первую строку, потом следующую.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Tesseract распознает только текст, но не число. Как это исправить?

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image = 'output.png'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image), lang = 'rus')
with open('log.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Вывод:

```
Степная лошадь

Пустынная лошадь
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь много вопросов и ответов на эту тему, иногда сводится к тому что бы правильно настроить Tesseract-OCR.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract


def main():
    image_path = 'image.png'
    image_data = Image.open(image_path)
    # pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' # Пути могут не совпадать
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_data, config='--psm 4 --oem 3', lang='rus')
    print(text) # Степная лошадь 4 273
                # Пустынная лошадь 10 350


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Там ещё какой то символ выводится, но это уже можно исправить функциями для обработки текста.